# How to read timezone from server request in spring reactive

Tags: java, timezone, spring-webflux, spring-rest

How to read timezone from server request in spring reactive, do we have alternative from RequestContextUtils in spring reactive programming

```
    TimeZone timezone = RequestContextUtils.getTimeZone(request);
```

This is not working in spring reactive